# Quick way to set a bitmask from a boolean in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitmask

It's common to perform a check and set/clear a flag, eg:

```
if (some_test) {
   flag |= SOME_FLAG;
}
else {
   flag &= ~SOME_FLAG;
}
```

A convenient way around this I found so far is...

```
flag = (some_test) ? (flag | SOME_FLAG) : (flag & ~SOME_FLAG);
```

This could be made into a macro and its OK, but is there some *bit-twiddeling* magic to avoid referencing flag twice?

*(in case multiple instantiations of `flag` causes overhead)*.

Example of what I'm looking for (if C could do ternary operations on operators), is...

```
flag ((some_test) ? (|=) : (&= ~) SOME_FLAG;
```

*The example above is only to describe what I'm looking for, of course it wont work in its current form.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
flag |= SOME_FLAG
```

is an expression, so you can use a macro

```
#define SET_FLAG(flag, some_test) \
    ((some_test) ? ((flag) |= SOME_FLAG) : ((flag) &= ~SOME_FLAG))
```

which evaluates `flag` only once, and when you use it, you need to type `flag` only once.

```
SET_FLAG(a->b->c->d, test);
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, this looks like the best option. I was wondering if there was some combination of bitmasking operators that could do this neatly (with a single operator), but seems not.

Comment: there is if you think about introducing variable length bitshifts (<< and >>) and detecting which power of 2 your flag is... but there is little benefit to that, its more complicated and less performant. certainly not a succinct solution

Answer (score 3):

I know you don't want to access flag twice. But you should be sure that is where the cost is.  Often, the conditional jump is more expensive.  On the last embedded processor I worked on, the fastest code would have looked like this:

```
 flag &= ~(SOME_FLAG);
 flag |= (some_test!=0) * SOME_FLAG;
```

Comment: note however that on many common platforms (x86, ppc, arm) ?: compiles to a conditional move rather than branching - which can be cheaper than an integer multiply

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a macro and have it avoid evaluating the mask twice then you could do it like this:

```
#define SETT(FLAG, MASK_T, MASK, TEST) \
do {\
  MASK_T mask = (MASK);\
  FLAG &= ~mask;\
  FLAG |= ((TEST) != 0) * mask;\
}\
while(false)

#define SET(FLAG, MASK, TEST) SETT(FLAG, unsigned, MASK, TEST)
```

Comment: disadvantage with this is it does multiple writes to FLAG that the compiler may not optimize out.

Comment: @ideasman42 The conditional is going to be slower than an extra bitwise op.

Comment: maybe (though the conditional could evaluate to a constant too - so not necessarily) - but you can still evaluate that once and apply the bitwise op once too - other examples given here do it.