# Is it possible to simplify the setter of this bitmask wrapper?

Tags: objective-c, boolean-expression

Consider the following code snippets:

In .h:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, ActionTrigger) {
    bitmask0            = 1 << 0,
    bitmask1            = 1 << 1,
    ...
};
@property (nonatomic) ActionTrigger notificationTrigger;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL actionNotificationPacketReceived;
```

In .m:

```
- (BOOL)actionNotificationPacketReceived    {
    return ((self.notificationTrigger   & bitmask0) == bitmask0);
}

- (void)setActionNotificationPacketReceived:(BOOL)value {
    if (value) {
        self.notificationTrigger |= bitmask0;
    } else {
        self.notificationTrigger &= ~bitmask0;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace the if/else statement in `-setActionNotificationPacketReceived:` with pure boolean logic?

**EDIT**

I ended up using the following Macro, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13262717/1623781).

```
#define OptionSetBool(option, flag, a_bool) ((a_bool) ? ((option) |= flag) : ((option) &= ~flag))
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166895/declaring-and-checking-comparing-bitmask-enums-in-objective-c ?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the linked article does not talk about setting bit masks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "pure boolean logic"?